# IPSec optional advanced questions [homework] AH/ESP and Tunnel/Transport modes

Tags: ipsec

I have 2 questions regarding IPSec. This is the last 2 optional questions of my homework:

1. Scenario when combining AH and ESP can be needed?
2. Scenario when combining Tunnel and Transport modes can be needed?

These are the optional questions, but I am just curious and can't answer on my own.

Answer (score 1):

[#1 Transport Adjacency](http://people.freebsd.org/~julian/IPSEC_4_Dummies.html) This is where you need the entire packet authenticated but also in ESP transport mode.

[#2 Dynamic routing](http://www.isi.edu/touch/pubs/draft-touch-ipsec-vpn-04.txt) This is what happens when you need the tunnel end-to-end, but need the path through the untrusted network to be dynamically assigned (i.e. resiliency).